# Matrix with ArrayList

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

I got this class :

```
import java.util.*;

public class MatrixArrayList extends AbstractMatrix {
    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> values;

    public MatrixArrayList(int nbl, int nbc) {
        super(nbl, nbc);
        values=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
    }


    @Override
    public int getValue(int x, int y) {
        return values.get(x).get(y) ;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(int x, int y, int value) {
        values.get(x).set(y, value);

    }   
}
```

and I got

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

I want to make a matrix with an `ArrayList`
i have w problem with this : 
valeurs.get(x).set(y, valeur);

Comment: i have a problem with this        valeurs.get(x).set(y, valeur);

Comment: Do you have to do this with lists? A 2D array implementation would probably be somewhat simpler.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your code which call causes the exception, however it is clear that you are not initializing your inner array-list, nor are you adding any objects to it.

When you initialize it in the constructor:

```
values=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

What you're basically doing is instantiating the `values` object to be an ArrayList of size 0 (no items have been added to it yet).

Then, if say, you're doing `setValue` at index `0`, you get the exception because when you do `get(x)`, you're basically doing `get(0)` on a collection of size 0 - there is nothing to get, you exceed the bounds of the your array.

What you might want to do is initialize all arrays in the constructor:

```
public MatrixArrayList(int nbl, int nbc) {
    super(nbl, nbc);
    values=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(nbl);
    for (int i = 0; i < nbl; i++) {
        values.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(nbc));
    }
}
```

And then you can access them without a problem in `getValue` or `setValue` (you'll get this exception if you actually do exceed the bounds or if you haven't set any value at the specific index yet. See comment below:).

Notice, though, that since you're using the `ArrayList` object, rather than a primitive `int[]` array, you still don't have values inside your array. Simply doing `new ArrayList<Integer>()` or even `new ArrayList<Integer>(num)` still leaves you with a list of size 0. If you want to cover all your bases, you might want to either initailize your ArrayList, or perform bounds checks before each `get` you make in either `getValue` or `setValue`.

Answer (score 0):

`new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>()` creates an empty list. To fill that list with values, you need to call `add()`.

Assuming you want to fill matrix with `nbl` lists of `nbc` null values:

```
this.values = new ArrayList<>(nbl);
for (int i = 0; i < nbl; i++) {
    ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>(nbc);
    for (int j = 0; j < nbc; j++)
        row.add(null);
    this.values.add(row);
}
```

You could also fill it with `0` values if you want.

Of course, if the matrix cannot change size, it would likely be much better to create a simple array version, instead of the `ArrayList` version you're trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Shell {
    static List<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>> read(String filename) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> A = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> B = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>();

        String thisLine;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

            // Begin reading A
            while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if (thisLine.trim().equals("")) {
                    break;
                } else {
                    ArrayList<Double> line = new ArrayList<Double>();
                    String[] lineArray = thisLine.split("\t");
                    for (String number : lineArray) {
                        line.add((double) Integer.parseInt(number));
                    }
                    A.add(line);
                }
            }

            // Begin reading B
            while ((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                ArrayList<Double> line = new ArrayList<Double>();
                String[] lineArray = thisLine.split("\t");
                for (String number : lineArray) {
                    line.add((double) Integer.parseInt(number));
                }
                B.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e);
        }

        List<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>> res = new LinkedList<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>>();
        res.add(A);
        res.add(B);
        return res;
    }

    static int[][] ijkAlgorithm(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> A,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> B) {
        int n = A.size();

        // initialise C
        int[][] C = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
                    C[i][j] += A.get(i).get(k) * B.get(k).get(j);
                }
            }
        }
        return C;
    }

    static void printMatrix(Matrix matrix, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(matrix.length);
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                if (j != 0) {
                    sb.append("\t");
                }
                String formattedString = String.format("%.0f", matrix.get(i, j))
                sb.append(formattedString);
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String filename;
        if (args.length < 2) {
            filename = "2000.in";
        } else {
            filename = args[1];
        }
        List<ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>>> matrices = read(filename);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> A = matrices.get(0);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> B = matrices.get(1);
        int n = A.size();
        double[][] Aarray = new double[n][n];
        double[][] Barray = new double[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                Aarray[i][j] = A.get(i).get(j);
                Barray[i][j] = B.get(i).get(j);
            }
        }
        Matrix AM = new Matrix(Aarray);
        Matrix BM = new Matrix(Aarray);
        Matrix CM = AM.times(BM);

        printMatrix(CM, n);
    }

}
```

input file that have matrices you want to do this operation

Hope this code helps happy coding.

Comment: Could you explain how the code is useful for the OP?

Comment: i did not get better idea to input matrix elements so i used file concept here if you had any problem you can initialize arraylist with matrix elements